# Powershell 7 / core in MobaXterm

Tags: powershell, mobaxterm, powershell-core

Is it possible to add a new (saved) session to MobaXterm for Powershell 7 / future versions of Powershell Core?

Currently the only option when adding a new shell session is "Powershell", which adds a Powershell 5 / Desktop session.

[image: add new powershell session in mobaxterm]

Answer (score 1):

The solution of elwyn doens't work for me because a new tab opens the basic powershell shell.

To bypass this open a regular powershell 5, open the profile `notepad $PROFILE` and just add `pwsh.exe` to it. Like this it isn't resetted everytime.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I wanted to keep my profile clean so I was still able to easily run Powershell 5 and Powershell Core separately, and not have PS5 always launch into Core.

Answer (score 0):

I have got this going by manually running `pwsh.exe` when starting a new Powershell (5) session.
So in the Session Settings dialog, under "Advanced Shell settings" add `pwsh.exe` to the "Execute the following command at startup" input:

This opens a new tab set to Powershell 5. Then pwsh.exe immediately runs, to launch Powershell Core in that same tab.

[image: Config for powershell core in mobaxterm]

I also ended up setting my startup dir in there as well, as the MobaXterm "Startup director" didn't seem to work for the nested pwsh.exe:

```
pwsh.exe -NoExit -Command { cd "C:\foo\bar" }
```